# Reading data from Excel with Openxlsx into R shows minor differences

Tags: r, openxlsx

I am reading the number `433256.5297400900000000` from an Excel file using `openxlsx`. In R it appears as `433256.529740090366`. A minor difference of -4.36557456851006E-10.

If I read the number of a csv-file, there is no difference.

If I read the number using `readxl::read.xlsx`, the same happens.

Does this have to do with numerical precision or should this not happen?

Comment: Yes, it is an issue with numeric precision. Excel displays zero for decimals that exceed its numeric precision:  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Numeric_precision_in_Microsoft_Excel

Comment: But the number in Excel is not a calculation  and the trailing zeros are there.

Comment: I put in 433256.529740090366 into Excel. It displayed 433256.5297400900000000. I suggest you do the same and then extract the value with openxlsx to see which value is actually stored in Excel.

Comment: If you want to know what value Excel has stored, look into the xml file. Open the xlsx file with a zip tool and look at the xml file in xl/worksheets. The value you are looking for should look something like this: `<v>433256.52974009</v>`. For reference, if I assign this `x <- 433256.529740090366` on Mac and Linux, `as.character(x)` tells me `433256.52974009`. Id say it's the usual spurious float number precision.

Comment: @JanMarvin That's documented in `help("as.character")` but conversion of numbers to strings is a different (although related) issue than internal precision vs printing/displaying.

Comment: Yes, but that's basically what happens in openxlsx of which I'm somehow the current sole developer. The values are imported from XML tags as characters and once they are in, atof() is applied which is similar to as.numeric() on my machine.

Comment: @JanMarvin OK, but `as.numeric` loses much less precision than `as.character`: see `sprintf("%.20f", as.numeric("433256.529740090366"))`. OP's issue is that openxlsx **appears** to lose precision but Excel actually displays less precision than it stores internally (as does R by default, although R is more clever and doesn't just print digits beyond precision as 0).

Comment: The important question for me as developer of said package is which result should be returned to R. If I enter the number above in my Windows Excel it prints as mentioned above. In the XML file it is written as <v>...009002</v>. Therefore with internal rounding. I'd say only the value shown in excel should be returned to R and the precision OP was asking about is imho wrong. Wrong in a negligible way, but wrong nonetheless. Obviously Excel is not a database, but if someone uses Excel, I have to assume they have a reason.